# Creating a new dictionary from mapping of flattened nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, flatten

I was wondering if there is a quick and pythonic way to create a dictionary based on certain keys of a dictionary?

For instance, if I have this given dictionary

```
{
  "a": "abc",
  "b": {"b1": "1", "b2": "2", "b3": "3"},
  "c": 1,
  "d": "timmy",
  "e": "John"
}
```

I want to be able to create a new dictionary with a one to one mapping based on only a few keys of the given dictionary. So in this example, I want to create a dictionary based on only the keys `"b2"`,`"c"`, and `"d"`. I would also want to give these keys a different name as well. The desired output would be:

```
{
  "out_b2": "2",
  "out_c": 1,
  "out_d": "timmy"
}
```

The easiest procedure I can come up with is to create nested for loops perform this task. I was wondering if there is a more efficient method to achieve this goal.

I understand that his question can be confusing depending on the situation of inputs and outputs. Lets keep it simple and say the deepest level is a max of one subdictionary for input and the output will NOT have any subdictionaries

Comment: Pretty unclear. Could you show some more example? Could there be more sub-directories?

Comment: @tobias_k i think I can understand why you would be confused. I will update the question shortly

Comment: Well you can't avoid having to recursively flatten all nested subdicts, unless you have some heuristic to know that key `b2` is located in subdict `d['b']`, or unless all desired keys happen to be found in the toplevel. Is there more missing information you need to tell us? Are we supposed to guess what to recurse into next, based on ranked similarity to toplevel keys? That sounds more hassle than just recursing, already.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over your dictionary items and check if the value is a `dict` again loop over its items and check if the key is in your specified keys then add the item to new dictionary :

```
>>> old={
...   "a": "abc",
...   "b": {"b1": "1", "b2": "2", "b3": "3"},
...   "c": 1,
...   "d": "timmy",
...   "e": "John"
... }
>>> new={}
>>> for i, j in old.items():
...    if i in key:
...        new['out_'+i]=j
...    elif isinstance(j,dict):
...         for k, v in j.items():
...              if k in key:
...                   new['out_'+k]=v
... 
>>> new
{'out_d': 'timmy', 'out_b2': '2', 'out_c': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use another dictionary to hold the mapping from old name to desired name:

```
mappings = {
    'b.b2': 'out_b2',
    'c': 'out_c',
    'd': 'out_d',
}
```

Here I've used a `.` in the key to signify a subkey of a nested dictionary - if your keys are likely to have a `.` in them, use a different delimiter (a `/`, say). I'd use a helper function to turn that dotted-subkey notation into a value:

```
def get_node(d, path):
    if '.' not in path:
        return d[path]
    first, rest = path.split('.', 1)
    return get_node(d[first], rest)
```

Then getting the keys you want is trivial:

```
>>> old = {
  "a": "abc",
  "b": {"b1": "1", "b2": "2", "b3": "3"},
  "c": 1,
  "d": "timmy",
  "e": "John"
}
>>> {v: get_node(old, k) for k, v in mappings.iteritems()}
{'out_b2': '2', 'out_c': 1, 'out_d': 'timmy'}
```

I've used a dictionary comprehension in the last part - if your version of Python doesn't support that, you can use the following instead:

```
dict((v, get_node(old, k)) for k, v in mappings.iteritems())
```